# One way binding lost when user types something in input text box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this AngularJS code

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
app.controller('testController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.MyTypes = [
      { name: 'Option1', value: 100 },
      { name: 'Option2', value: 101 },
      { name: 'Other', value: 102 }
    ];

    $scope.SelectedType = $scope.MyTypes[0];
    $scope.SelectedValue = $scope.MyTypes[0].value;

    $scope.onChange = function () {
        $scope.SelectedValue = $scope.SelectedType.value;
    }

});
```

with this HTML

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="testController">    
        <select ng-model="SelectedType" ng-options="ft.name for ft in MyTypes" ng-change="onChange()"></select>
        <input type="text" value="{{SelectedValue}}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

This displays the value in the input box, taken from the selected item of the Select list as when items are selected from the list.
This code works fine until user types something in to the input textbox, then the binding is lost and the text box value does not get updated.

Is this a normal behavior in AngularJS?. How to overcome this and get it working (replace the entered text with the value from the select list when different item is selcted) even after the user types something in?

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/10386/)

Comment: Try ng-model="SelectedValue" for the input.

Comment: Gruff Bunny is right ^. You should probably also be aware of this issue with isolate scopes http://larseidnes.com/2014/11/05/angularjs-the-bad-parts/

Comment: ng-model was needed. fixed fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/10388/

Comment: @Nalaka526 what's idea behind one way binding input

Comment: @sylwester It has some default values for all the options except the option `Other`, which should allow the user to input a value, but again the user can select an option with a predefined value so the text box value (user entered) should be replaced.

Comment: @GruffBunny It worked. Can you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired effect you should bind the input to the SelectedValue using ng-model rather than having an interpolated value in the value attribute:

```
<input type='text' ng-model='SelectedValue' />
```

The key to the behaviour you're seeing is that the [**value**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) attribute on the input is the *initial* value of the control not the value of the input.

As soon as you enter text into the input field, whatever is in the value attribute is no longer relevant. The value attribute will contain the new value but it will not affect the value in the control (have a look in a DOM inspector).

Answer (score 0):

It's not normal behavior, You need to bind your text box. your are just setting the value in you text box but not binding like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="SelectedValue" value="{{SelectedValue}}"/>
```

Here is the updated code.[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/10403/)

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/10403/)